# Laravel Maatwebsite Excel - All zero values being populated by map() function using fromArray() concern

Tags: maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am trying to make an excel export using Maatwebsite Excel. This is my second export file and first one is working perfect. When I var_dump() data is okay using postman but the rendered excel has all cells populated with 0s.

```
class SummaryExport implements FromArray, WithMapping, WithEvents,  WithHeadings, WithStyles, WithCustomStartCell, WithStrictNullComparison, ShouldAutoSize
{

    use RegistersEventListeners;
    private $from_date, $to_date, $fee_type;
    public function __construct($from_date, $to_date, $fee_type)
    {
        $this->from_date = $from_date;
        $this->to_date = $to_date;
        $this->fee_type = $fee_type;
    }





    /**
    * @return array
    */
    
    public function array(): array
    {
        $school_id = auth()->user()->school_id;

        if($this->fee_type == "all"){
            $fee_vouchers = FeeVoucher::where('school_id', $school_id)->where('issue_date','>=',$this->from_date)
                            ->where('issue_date','<=',$this->to_date)->get();
        }else{
            $fee_vouchers = FeeVoucher::where('school_id', $school_id)->where('issue_date','>=',$this->from_date)
                            ->where('issue_date','<=',$this->to_date)
                            ->where('type', $this->fee_type)->get();   
        }

        $gross = 0;
        $concession = 0;
        $fines=0;
        $net=0;
        $received=0;
        $percentage=0;
        $balance = 0;
        $fee_summary = array();

        foreach($fee_vouchers as $vchr){
            $gross  = $gross + $vchr->total_amount + $vchr->fines->sum('amount');
            $concession  = $concession + $vchr->concessions->sum('applied');
            $fines  = $fines + $vchr->fines->sum('amount');
            if($vchr->is_paid == 1){
                $received  = $received + $vchr->total_amount + $vchr->fines->sum('amount');
            }
        }

        $net  = $gross - $concession;
        $balance = $net - $received; 

        $fee_summary[]= array(
            'gross' => intval($gross),
            'concession' =>intval($concession),
            'fines' => intval($fines),
            'net' => intval($net),
            'received' => intval($received),
            'percentage' => intval($percentage),
            'balance' => intval($balance)
        );

        //var_dump($fee_summary); //values are displayed correct here as well
        return $fee_summary;
        
        
    }
    
    public function map($row): array
    {
        // When I do var_dump($row) here in post man I can see data but in Excel data is not written but all zeros
        return [
            $row['gross'],
            $row['concession'],
            $row['fines'],
            $row['net'],
            $row['received'],
            $row['percentage'],
            $row['balance']
            //[15023,456,785,4567,865,952,0] // when I give static values the problem is fixed and all values are written in Excel
        ];
    }

    
}
```

The weird thing is when I give the fixed static values it gives me proper results. On using var_dump it also shows that data is accurately created. But I am stuck from last night what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old now, but the `intval` method will return zero on an unprocessable/incorrect value. As mentioned in the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), *The integer value of value on success, or 0 on failure. Empty arrays return 0, non-empty arrays return 1.*

```php
echo intval(true) // 1
echo intval(false) // 0
echo intval("'12'") // 0, within the quotes the value is a string still
echo intval("12") // 12
echo intval(5.25) // 5
echo intval('$400') // 0
```

Without seeing the input data I assume that the values being passed into the `intval` method on return, aren't valid types. Are there symbols (i.e. `$`, other currency symbols) within the values?

Comment: Thanks for the reply I really don't remember exactly now how I fixed this.